# Canvas not responding inside html script

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to show my image in the JavaScript canvas, but the code is not working. It is not showing anything. Where is my mistake?

I have tried to debug the code using Google's debugger but nothing has come up.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>

  <style>
    #canvas {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
  </style>
    </body>
    <script>
    const context;
    const gameCanvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    context=gameCanvas.getContext("2d");
    //context.canvas.height=500;
    //context.canvas.width=500;


    var imgObj = new Image();
    imgObj.src = "dragon.jpg";
    var x = 100;
    var y = 100;



    imgObj.onload = function(){
        context.drawImage(imgObj,x,y);
    }

</script>
</html>
```

I want to see a canvas and the image in that canvas when I load this html file.

Comment: Try putting the `JS` inside `<body>`

Comment: tried, didnt work

Comment: Your code works fine. https://jsfiddle.net/j31t6zxq/1/

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to re-initialise `const` context; you should be using `let` instead.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>

        <style>
            #canvas {
                position: absolute;
                top: 50%;
                left: 50%;
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            }
        </style>
    </body>
    <script>
        let context;
        const gameCanvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        context = gameCanvas.getContext('2d');

        var imgObj = new Image();
        imgObj.src = 'dragon.jpg';
        var x = 100;
        var y = 100;

        imgObj.onload = function() {
            context.drawImage(imgObj, x, y);
        };
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: make sure the image `dragon.jpg` is in same folder with your index.html | check code here -> https://codesandbox.io/embed/bitter-sunset-it3gp?fontsize=14